# Using Entity Framework in Modular Applications

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a core project that has my EF code and `DbContext`, which is then compiled. I have the DLL in my main website project and want to use code first migrations to update my database.

However, the models are defined in my web project and without being able to use code similar to this:

```
public virtual DbSet<AuthActivity> AuthActivity { get; set; }
```

I'm not sure how I can get this to work?

I call `Add-Migration`, but the migration is empty because although the model exists, it hasn't been declared as a `DbSet`, which I can't do because my `DbContext` exists in a compiled DLL.

Is there any way I can work around this?

Comment: You can't. The web application has the models and references the dll. The dll had to reference the web application to access the models. You see the circular reference?

Comment: I thought this was potentially the issue. I've managed to work around this by having the web project contain it's own `DbContext` that inherits from the core. I'd rather keep all EF code in the core project, but this is the next best approach.